# Unable to ssh EC2 instances in same subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have two EC2 instances in same subnet but I when I am trying to ssh from one instance to another I am getting publickey denied message, it does not prompt password

[root@ip-10-0-21-156 ~]# ssh testuser@10.0.21.170
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: Have you configured ssh on that server to use passwords instead of ssh keys? Since it isn't prompting for password it sounds like you have not.

Answer (score 0):

By default, EC2 instances are configured to provide SSH authentication via public/private keys.  So, just like you needed a private key (you likely downloaded the .pem file when you created the IAM keypair) installed on your local computer in order to SSH into the instance, you also need a private key installed on the instance in order to SSH from that instance into another instance.

What you didn't see behind the scenes was that when you launched the instance and specified the key-pair name, EC2 let you download the private key (.pem file), automatically created the user on the instance (e.g. on the Ubuntu AMI, the username is 'ubuntu' and on the Amazon Linux AMI, the username is 'ec2-user') AND it put the public key that matches the private key into the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.  All of that needs to happen before you can SSH into an instance.

So, assuming you launched the two instances with the same keypair, in order to SSH from instance A to instance B, everything has been done for you EXCEPT for putting the private key (the .pem file) into the ~/.ssh directory.  AWS considers keeping the private key on the instance a security risk and therefore does not do it automatically.  So, simply put the private key into the .ssh directory on instance A and then add it to your keyring or you can specify the key in the ssh command like so:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/PRIVATE_KEY.pem USERNAME@INSTANCE_B_LOCAL_IP
```

All that said, it's generally a bad idea to keep private keys for other instances on an EC2 instance and if you find yourself needing to do that, you should likely rethink your architecture for whatever it is your doing (i.e. there are probably better ways of doing it).

Additionally, you really shouldn't be using the EC2 created user account (i.e. ubuntu@ or ec2-user@) for normal day to day stuff or even to perform maintenance or other sysadmin work.  You should really create your own account, because the EC2 created account is essentially a root account.

AWS recommends continuing to use public/private key authentication for all accounts, however you could switch to use password-based authentication and then not need to worry about the keys.  This is inherently less secure than using key-based authentication, however given strict password requirements, you could increase security.

The only thing you will need to do when creating additional accounts (either password-based or key-based), is to make sure your personalized account has sudo access so you can sudo to do things that require root access.  In Ubuntu, you can do this by adding the following line to the /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users file:

```
USERNAME ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

While you're there, consider disabling the sudo access for the EC2 created username.  Even though no one else will have the key, everyone will know that there is an ubuntu account that has sudo access.  Just like with passwords, knowing the username is a substantial part of a hackers job.

Hope this helps.