# AWS EC2 SSH <private_ip_address> inside same subnet

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I have an instance A (public_ip_A) and an instance B (public_ip_B) both are in same subnet and security groups are open to ssh. And I am able to

```
ssh -i pem_file user@public_ip_A/B
```

Now after logging into instance A, I like to ssh to instance B without pem file using private ip.

I have looked at couple of documents to add key to ~/.ssh/authorized_key but was not clear to get the exact understanding. Any clue on how to achieve `ssh` using private ip ?

[Unable to ssh EC2 instances in same subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816287/unable-to-ssh-ec2-instances-in-same-subnet) 
 was not helpful.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com, unix.stackexchange.com, or ServerFault.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: If folks are interested in creating a venue for these types of questions, follow the proposal for a [dedicated Cloud Computing site on StackExchange](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110490/cloud-computing-aws-azure-google-openstack-etc?referrer=Gtut7wQSWPk88jFJz_zqMg2) and up-vote some sample questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: ok noted. thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has nothing to do with private IP or subnet. What you need is [ssh-agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent). ssh-agent is a program to hold private keys used for public key authentication.

Once you have ssh-agent running, add your private key(s) using [ssh-add](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add)

Place the corresponding public key in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on both machines, then you can `ssh` without supplying the private key.

Follow [Using an ssh-agent, or how to type your ssh password once, safely](http://rabexc.org/posts/using-ssh-agent) if you want step by step instructions.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two instances in the same VPC and you wish to SSH between then, you should connect via their **private IP address**. This means traffic stays totally within the VPC and instances it can work between both public and private subnets (whereas public IP addresses work only to instances in a public subnet).

Going via their Public IP address means the traffic exits the VPC but is then routed back in. There is a **1c/GB charge** for such traffic. The pricing page refers to this as Amazon EC2 instances connecting "Using a public or Elastic IPv4 address".

As to security, the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` defines which keys are permitted to login to the user (whose home directory has that file). You still need to provide a key when connecting, but this can be automated as per @helloV's answer.